# Why is the 2d plotly.js plot component divided into two separated svg after mounting the component from a htmlelement

Tags: reactjs, web-component, custom-element, plotly.js

I'm trying to wrap the Plotly.js React component inside Web Components. After mounting the plotly.js React component, the 2D plot is divided into two separated`main-svg`s, one for data and one for layout.[image]

Moreover, the events are activated on `main-svg` containing layout[image]

However, for a 3D plot, I didn't face this issue. The 2D plot and 3D plot are almost the same. The 3D plot just has one extra line to get `z data`. Also, the `type` is set to `'scatter3d'`.
[image]

The following code is the 2d plotly react component:

```
export class Sct2dClassComp extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {  
        data : props.data,
        layout : {
        xaxis:{
            title:'x-axis',
          },
          yaxis:{
            title:'y-axis',
          },
        hovermode:'closest',
        margin:{l:0, r:0, t:0, b:0},
        },
        config : {
        displaylogo: false,
        modeBarButtonsToRemove: [
        'autoScale2d',
        'hoverClosestCartesian',
        'hoverCompareCartesian',
        'toggleSpikelines',
        'pan2d',
        'zoomIn2d',
        'zoomOut2d',
        'zoom2d',
        'lasso2d'
        ],
        }
  };
 
}
 handleOnSelectedEvent = (event) => {
  window.alert("onSelected events fired onSelected event")
}
 handleOnClickEvent = (events)=>{
  window.alert("onClick events fired onClick event")
}
 componentDidMount(){
   axios.get('http://localhost:3003/sct')
        .then(resp => {
            const res_data = resp.data;
            if (res_data && res_data.length > 0) {
              const sct_data=[{
                x: res_data.map((item) => item.x),
                y: res_data.map((item) => item.y),
                // z: res_data.map((item) => item.z),
                mode: 'markers',
                type: 'scatter',
                marker:{
                  size: 7,
                  color: res_data.map((item) => item.color),
                  opacity: 0.8
                  },
                hovertemplate:res_data.map((item) => item.name)
              }] 
            this.setState({
              data : sct_data
            });
            }   
        })}

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
          <Plot
          data = {this.state.data}
          layout={this.state.layout}
          config={this.state.config}
          onClick={this.handleOnClickEvent}
          onSelected={this.handleOnSelectedEvent}  
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

And this is the corresponding custom element:

```
class Sct2dElement extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  connectedCallback() {

    this.mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadowRoot.appendChild(this.mountPoint);
    ReactDOM.render(<Sct2dClassComp />, this.mountPoint);
   
    retargetEvents(this.shadowRoot);
  }
  
  disconnectedCallback(){
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.mountPoint);
  }

}

customElements.define('sct2d-element', Sct2dElement);
```

I was wondering if someone has any ideas about the reason behind this issue, and how I can fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the question. Is there a particular requirement for using the react wrapped version of Plotly.js? Plotly.js vends a native javascript API which would remove the complexity of using React within a custom element: https://plotly.com/javascript/getting-started/

Comment: Additionally I think the issue may be that Plotly relies on global styling. The shadow DOM encapsulates styles by default. See these Plotly issues: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+shadow+DOM

Does your problem go away if skipping the `attachShadow` and using `this.appendChild(this.mountPoint)`? See this sample: https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=314a145c03b6aaf4e1a70f42b6e1b1ba

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. That was quite helpful. I removed the ```attachShadow``` and the issue's solved. 
Regarding using react wrapped, I've been developing a web-based app in reactjs. Now, I need to consume the developed components in an Angular application. Therefore, I am wrapping the react components inside custom elements.

Comment: Thank you! I've added my comment as an answer so this question can be marked answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because `const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });` is adding [Shadow DOM](https://web.dev/shadowdom-v1/) which provides encapsulated CSS. In this specific case this isn't ideal because the Plotly.js library depends on global CSS styles, so the styles are not applied within the component's `shadowRoot`.
Until [Plotly fixes issues with Shadow DOM](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+shadow+DOM), a workaround is to not create any Shadow DOM, e.g:

```js
class ExampleEl extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
    this.appendChild(mountPoint);
    Plotly.newPlot(mountPoint, [{
      x: [1,2,3,4,5],
      y: [1,2,4,8,16],
      margin: {t:0},
    }]);
  }
}

customElements.define('example-el', ExampleEl)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.1.min.js"></script>

<example-el></example-el>
```